# Clickable icon in vf page

Tags: visualforce

i want an image icon in my vf page ,and when i click it certain javascript should be invoked.

i could add an image and invoke javascript but it does not look like clickable .Handpointer tool doesn't appear.i added an apex: out panel,specified an image and put an action support event for invoking javascript.It works as well.

But how to make hand tool appear?

Comment: Add `style="cursor:pointer;"` to your panel.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the image in an anchor element, and the hand cursor will appear normally. You can also use a button to cause the hand cursor to appear.

### Examples

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomething()"><img src="some-url"/></a>

<apex:outputLink action="{!doSomething}"><apex:image url="some-url"/></apex:outputLink>

<apex:outputLink onclick="doSomething()"><apex:image url="some-url"/></apex:outputLink>

<button onclick="doSomething()"><img src="some-url"/></button>
```

Comment: FYI: You can eliminate the border with CSS.

Comment: That is true, but it simply takes extra effort than using a normal link with a button.

Answer (score 1):

Add `style="cursor:pointer;"` to your panel. – mast0r

answers the questions :)